# Storing large size images from canvas html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

There js script loading and manipulation of the image using the library fabricjs. The dimensions of the canvas 600x350 pixels. If the canvas upload images smaller, and after I save the canvas with a file on disk, then everything is fine. But when I load the image into the canvas larger than the size of the canvas (viewport) and then save the file to disk, then why is scribbled image to the size of the canvas.
Please tell me how to save the image from the canvas that is larger than the size of the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make the canvas larger, because anything that doesn't fit in the canvas is deleted.